# Nil Value From Lisp Function

Tags: lisp

Why does the following code return a nil value instead of 1?

```
(defun test (list)
                  (car(list)))

(test '( 1 2 3))
```

Comment: What is the value of `(list`)? What is the value of `(car (list))`?

Comment: I am attempting to make the function take the CAR of the list provided to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns `nil` because you're asking what the `car` of `(list)` is, which is a function invocation of the `list` function. Since you're passing the `list` function no arguments, it is returning `nil` since there is no `car` nor `cdr` (it's an empty list). The following would produce the desired effect:

```
(defun test (list)
  (car list))
(test '(1 2 3)) ;; now returns 1
```